# It shows error 404 using python manage.py run server

Tags: python, django

Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/

The current path, new_topic/, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please add ```urls.py``` and the path you hit.

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page.
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    
    # Show all topics.
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
    
    # Detail page for a single topic.
    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
    url(r'^new_topic/$',views.new_topic,name='new_topic'),
]

Comment: my question is why i am getting error 404